# Problemas com CRUD utilizando MySQL

Tags: mysql, c, banco-de-dados, crud

Boa noite pessoal, venho pedir uma ajuda referente a inserção e consulta ao MySQL utilizando C. Eu estou tentando criar um simples CRUD, porem estou tendo problemas com o método  de consulta.

Eu queria que o método exibisse o seguinte: Nome,matricula,curso,telefone e email na primeira linha e logo abaixo as informações das tuplas,uma por uma de maneira organizada.

Porem ela exibe as informaçãoes totalmente desorganizadas,uma tupla esta ocupando mais de uma linha, alem disso nao aparece corretamente os nomes das colunas da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Eu utilizando o CodeBlocks 17.12 com o compilador GNU

Tabelas do banco de dados universidade:

```
create table aluno(

nome varchar(100) not null,
matricula int,
curso varchar(50) not null,
telefone varchar(20) not null,
email varchar(75), 
primary key(matricula)

); 

create table professor(

nome varchar(100) not null,
matricula int,
disciplina varchar(50) not null,
telefone varchar(20) not null,
email varchar(75),
primary key(matricula)

);
```

Variaveis globais,include e define:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NOME 100
#define CURSO 40
#define TEL 20
#define EMAIL 75

MYSQL conexao;
int statusConexao;
char query[100];
```

Metodos  (Coloquei apenas aqueles que envolvem o problema):

```
void cadastroAluno(void){

mysql_init(&conexao);
char nome[NOME];
int matricula;
char curso[CURSO];
char telefone[TEL];
char eMail[EMAIL];

system("cls");
printf("Cadastro de alunos\n\n");
setbuf(stdin,NULL);

printf("Digite o nome:");
fgets(nome,NOME,stdin);
nome[strcspn(nome,"\n")] = 0;

printf("Digite a matricula:");
scanf("%d",&matricula);

setbuf(stdin,NULL);

printf("Digite o curso:");
fgets(curso,CURSO,stdin);
curso[strcspn(curso,"\n")] = 0;

setbuf(stdin,NULL);

printf("Digite o telefone:");
fgets(telefone,TEL,stdin);
telefone[strcspn(curso,"\n")] = 0;

setbuf(stdin,NULL);

printf("Digite o e-mail:");
fgets(eMail,EMAIL,stdin);
eMail[strcspn(eMail,"\n")] = 0;

setbuf(stdin,NULL);


    if(mysql_real_connect(&conexao,"localhost", "root", "", "universidade", 3306, NULL, 0)){

        sprintf(query,"INSERT INTO aluno(nome,matricula,curso,telefone,email) values('%s','%d','%s','%s','%s');",nome,matricula,curso,telefone,eMail);

       statusConexao = mysql_query(&conexao,query);

       if(!statusConexao){
            printf("Cadastro concluído com sucesso\nLinhas afetadas:%d\n",mysql_affected_rows(&conexao));
       }else{
            printf("Falha no cadastro.Tente novamente\n");
       }
       system("PAUSE");
       mysql_close(&conexao);

    }else{

        printf("Falha na conexão ao banco de dados\n");
        printf("Erro %d: %s\n", mysql_errno(&conexao), mysql_error(&conexao));

    }

 }
```

---

```
void consultaAlunoSim(void){

system("cls");
mysql_init(&conexao);
MYSQL_RES * resp;
MYSQL_ROW linhas;
MYSQL_FIELD * campos;
int contador;
char querySimples[] = "SELECT * FROM aluno;";

if(mysql_real_connect(&conexao, "localhost", "root", "", "universidade", 3306, NULL, 0)){

    if(mysql_query(&conexao,querySimples)){
        printf("Erro: %s\n:",mysql_error(&conexao));
    }else{

        resp = mysql_store_result(&conexao);

        if(resp){

            campos = mysql_fetch_field(resp);

            for(contador = 0; contador < mysql_num_fields(resp); contador++){
                printf("%s",(campos[contador].name));

                if(mysql_num_fields(resp) > 1){
                    printf("\t");
                }

            }

            printf("\n");

            while((linhas = mysql_fetch_row(resp))!= NULL){

                for(contador = 0; contador < mysql_num_fields(resp); contador++){
                    printf("%s\t",linhas[contador]);
                }
                printf("\n");

            }
        }

        system("PAUSE");
        mysql_free_result(resp);
        mysql_close(&conexao);

    }

}else{
    printf("Falha na conexão ao banco de dados\n");
    printf("Erro %d : %s\n",mysql_errno(&conexao),mysql_error(&conexao));
  }

}
```

Comment: Olha - não olhei seu código com atenção - mas porquê você põe uma variável global "query" com apens 100 bytes de buffer ? `char query[100];`  - a primeira query que você usa, antes da substituição dos parâmetros, já usa 88  bytes. -  deve ir pra perto de 200 bytes feitas as substituições. Isso pode até não ser o responsável pelos problemas que voce está tendo  mas é um problema seríssimo que pode fazer seu programa travar a qualquer momento.  Ponha pelo menos 4096 de tamanho para essa query - em nenhum PC isso vai fazer qualquer diferença

Comment: Obrigado pela observação jsbueno. Eu deveria deixar a variavel global query assim -> query[4096] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quanto ao problema que você detectou em si, é apenas uma questão de formatação da saída - o compilador C não vai inventar uma forma de abreviar um nome de cerca de 40 caracteres "José dos Santos  Pereira" numa coluna de pouco mais de 6 caracteres  "nome   ".  Você tem que fazer algum código sofisticado para deixar um espaço apropriado para a largura das colunas, e possivelmente abreviar o conteúdo de colunas que sejam maiores - 
Ou seja, em posse dos resultados da query, verificar o tamanho máximo do "nome" e adicionar um número apropriado de espaços após a palavra "nome" no topo da coluna. E ainda criar uma forma de alinhar os resultados nas outras colunas - se um nome tem 20 caracteres, e o da segunda linha tem 30 caracteres, a segunda coluna (matricula), só pode ter seus valores impressos a partir da coluna 31.  Você está usando o caractere tab (`\t`) que faz essa mágica - mas apenas para campos que variem até 7 caracteres no comprimento.  O *tab* fica no máximo com o equivalente  a 8 espaços de largura.

Na verdade o que ocorre é que mostrar dados bem formatados num terminal de textos está *longe* de ser uma tarefa das mais simples, e o uso da linguagem C, que é uma linguagem comparativamente de baixo nível, para manipular dados textuais não ajuda.

Para comparação, o link abaixo é para um código em Python que faz isso - exibe resultados tabulares no terminal - é a parte da aplicação que faz só isso, os dados em si são passados como parâmetros de outros pontos da mesma aplicação - essa á uma aplicação para "produção", mais sofisticada, que pode desenhar molduras em volta das colunas, etc... e mesmo ela não tem um mecanismo de abreviar o tamanho dos dados nas colunas.  Mas tem toda a parte que seria necessária no seu código para calcular a largura de cada coluna antes da impressão da tabela, etc...

https://github.com/turicas/rows/blob/develop/rows/plugins/txt.py

Em suma - é legal você brincar com esse seu código para aprendizado - mas se realmente estiver desenvolvendo uma aplicação para uso que vá manipular esses dados no banco de dados a sugestão forte é:

1) Passar para outra linguagem de programação - (em que por examplo, você não tenha que se preocupar com o tamanho em bytes do buffer da query para o MySQL, como comentei na questão). Sugiro estudar uma linguagem dinâmica de muito alto nível como Python, Javascript ou Ruby (PHP já tem algumas idiossincrasias que podem introduzir vícios nessa sua etapa de aprendizado - não recomendaria - em particular você vai ficar muito tentado a misturar código com apresentação)

2) Mesmo passando a usar uma aplicação dessas, o uso do terminal a partir de certo ponto vai complicar a aplicação tanto para você como desenvolvedor (como você pode ver no link acima, o uso de Python não reduz magicamente a complexidade de exibir uma tabela no terminal de forma correta a zero). Então é legal pegar um framework web e desenvolver a aplicação para web  - é bem mais simples colocar a saída da query num bnaco em que cada campo fica dentro de uma tag `<td>...</td>` do que se preocupar manualmente com a largura da tabela (ademais, com a saída em html, você pode separadamente, com CSS, limitar a largura das colunas e configurar para truncar os dados, ou exibição de barras de rolagem na suas células).

3) Se você estiver a fim de permanecer no C para aprender mesmo, ainda assim, eu recomendaria então mudar o foco da sua aplicação para gerar as saídas em arquivos do tipo ".csv", que você pode abrir num programa de planilha - e você poderá se focar no controle e operação do banco de dados em si na sua app.  (perceba que nas linguagens que citei acima, interagir com o banco de dados também é proporcionalmente mais fácil).

(Quanto ao seu código atual eu nem sei como você conseguiu o resultado parcial com os nomes das colunas  - a sua imagem mostra 5 colunas, mas você só faz uma chamada a `mysql_fetch_field` que é o que retorna informações, inclusive o nome, das colunas, e não faz isso em nenhum laço - já que a função só traz a informação de uma coluna por vez:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-fetch-field.html

Ou seja, se esse é o código que realmente gera o resultado que você mostra, a expressão `campos[contador].name`  só está funcionando por acaso, por conta de uma característica não documentada da função do mysql)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda jsbueno. Essa tentativa em C e mais pra aprendizado mesmo, nunca tinha feita conexao a BD em nenhuma linguagem, vi um tutorial ensinando a fazer em C e resolvi tentar. Vou pesquisar sobre esses arquivos do tipo ".csv"